# Pygame and pygame.time.wait() function is working in a bizarre way

Tags: python, time, pygame, wait, sleep

I am trying to change the pygame screen. First, I draw a rect. Then, I fill the screen again. In-between I add wait function to see the change. When I run program, screen starts black and waits for every wait function without doing any changes. Then, it shows the end result.

```
import pygame
BlockList=[]
pygame.init()
block_side_length=30
black = 0,0,0
GameArea_start_x=5
GameArea_start_y=5
GameArea_width=300
GameArea_height=270
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tetris")
gameDisplay.fill((0,100,100))
GameArea = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,[GameArea_start_x,GameArea_start_y,GameArea_width,GameArea_height])
lowest_block_y =GameArea_start_y+GameArea_height-block_side_length
pygame.time.wait(2000)
gameDisplay.fill((0,100,100))
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,(0,250,0),[50,50,40,90])
pygame.time.wait(2000)
gameDisplay.fill((0,100,100))
GameArea
```

Output:

[image]

After 4 secs

[image]

Note: I am trying to draw the rectangle by calling its name. It doesn't work. Is there any similar fashion?

Comment: Please be consistent with your naming. Use the naming conventions described in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) where variables and functions are in `lower_snake_case`, classes in `PascalCase` and constants in `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update what is shown in the pygame window, you must call [pygame.display.update()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update), like so:

```
import pygame
BlockList=[]
pygame.init()
block_side_length=30
black = 0,0,0
GameArea_start_x=5
GameArea_start_y=5
GameArea_width=300
GameArea_height=270
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((400,300))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tetris")
gameDisplay.fill((0,100,100))
GameArea = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black,[GameArea_start_x,GameArea_start_y,GameArea_width,GameArea_height])
lowest_block_y =GameArea_start_y+GameArea_height-block_side_length
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(2000)
gameDisplay.fill((0,100,100))
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,(0,250,0),[50,50,40,90])
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(2000)
gameDisplay.fill((0,100,100))
pygame.display.update()
```

Note that your approach of calling `pygame.time.wait()` for long periods of time will cause the window to freeze and become unresponsive while waiting. Some better approaches are described in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306233/waiting-without-freezing-everything).